# How to let tamejs automatically compile all .tjs files into .js?

Tags: auto-compile, tamejs

I'm interested in tamejs, and want to use it in my project.

But I don't want to manually compile them into js files before running/testing, etc. I want to let tamejs monitor a directory, and automatically compiles .tjs to .js when the files change.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

This is discussed in the README: https://github.com/maxtaco/tamejs

```
require ('tamejs').register (); // register the *.tjs suffix
require ("mylib.tjs");          // then use node.js's import as normal
```

Answer (score -1):

var myTamedModule = require("./app.tjs");

Comment: `.tjs` is not javascript, it needs compilation before `require`

Comment: Once you import tamejs itself the behaviour of the require function changes. You do not need to compile before you require.